# IBM MobileFirst Sever support load balancing?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i have read ibm mobilefirst documents but cannot found content about load balancing. Does MFP support load balancing ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. IBM MobileFirst Server support load balancing. Actually it is the underlying app servers on which MFP is running is responsible in handling.

MFP Server runs on AppServers like WebSphere Application Servers (Liberty Profile or Full profile) or Tomcat. So any of the load balancing related documentations for the above App servers would help you achieve the same.

Following links might be of help for your reference.

- [Typical MF Topologies](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_typical_topology_of_an_ibm_wor.html)
- [Session Independent mode in MFP Cluster](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_session_indep.html)

Comment: Tks for your help. I have read the documents you suggest but still don't know where to start. What I need to install. Can you support me a bit more

Comment: You should start with getting a multi server configuration ( cluster / liberty farm ) working with loadbalancer . Once this is done and ready, you can deploy MFP on to this configuration.